# Why can't POST methods be called

Tags: php, slim

```
$app->get(
    '/',
    function() {
        echo "<h1>Android Programming HW7";
        echo "<form action=\"http://rangtian.yu.com/post\" method=\"post\">";
        echo "First name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"><br>";
        echo "ID: <input type=\"text\" name=\"id\"><br>";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">";
        echo "</form>";
    }
);

$app->post(
    '/post',
    function($request, $response, $args) {
        echo 'This is a POST route.<br>';
        //$data = $request->getParsedBody();
        //echo $data['name']."<br>";
        //echo $data['id'];
    }
);
```

I'm new to PHP and Slim. When I use the get function like rootAddress/, post can be shown in browser correctly.

But if I try to call post directly like typing rootAddress/post in browser, error will occur, says "Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST"

Why?

Comment: of course it won't work. typing a url on the browser and press enter always is a GET, use a chrome extention like POSTman REST to simulate a POST request

Comment: New to Http in general. Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp